# Erlang. Correct way to stop process

Tags: erlang

Good day, i have following setup for my little service:

```
-module(mrtask_net).

-export([start/0, stop/0, listen/1]).

-define(SERVER, mrtask_net).

start() ->
    Pid = spawn_link(fun() -> ?MODULE:listen(4488) end),
    register(?SERVER, Pid),
    Pid.

stop() ->
    exit(?SERVER, ok).

....
```

And here is the repl excerpt:

```
(emacs@rover)83> mrtask_net:start().
<0.445.0>
(emacs@rover)84> mrtask_net:stop().
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  exit/2
        called as exit(mrtask_net,ok)
     in call from mrtask_net:stop/0
(emacs@rover)85>
```

As you see, stopping process produces error, process is stopping though.
What does this error mean and how to make thing clean ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not being an Erlang programmer and just from the documentation of `exit` ([here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#exit-2)), I'd say, that `exit` requires a process id as first argument whereas you are passing an atom (`?SERVER`) to it.

Try

```
exit(whereis(?SERVER), ok).
```

instead (`whereis` returns the process id associated with a name, see [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html))

Comment: +1 Being able to read documentation can be just as valuable as knowing a language inside out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the call to `exit/2` as @MartinStettner has pointed out. The reason the process stops anyway is that you have started it with `spawn_link`. Your process is then linked to the shell process. When you called `mrtask_net:stop()` the error caused the shell process to crash which then caused your process to crash as they were linked. A new shell process is then automatically started so you can keep working with the shell. You generally do want to start your servers with `spawn_link` but it can cause confusion when your are testing them from the shell and they just "happen" to die.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to stick with OTP. It really gives you tons of advantages (I hardly can immagine the case where OTP doesn't benefit).

So, if you want to stop process in OTP you should do something like this for `gen_server`:

```
% process1.erl
% In case you get cast message {stopme, Message}
handle_cast({stopme, Message}, State) ->
    % you will stop
    {stop, normal, State}
handle_cast(Msg, State) ->
    % do your stuff here with msg
    {noreply, State}.

% process2.erl
% Here the code to stop process1
gen_server:cast(Pid, {stopme, "It's time to stop!"}),
```

More about it you can find here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html